# How to evaluate a single expression in Haskell mode for Emacs?

Tags: haskell, emacs

In Lisp or Scheme buffers it is possible to evaluate a single expression by pressing <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd> which calls `eval-last-sexp`. But `eval-last-sexp` works only for literals in Haskell. What is the equivalent way to do the same in the Haskell mode?

Comment: In fact, `eval-last-sexp` does not work with Haskell mode at all.  If it appears to be working with a literal, it is because that the literal syntax is similar in Haskell and in Lisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval-last-sexp` is a command from `emacs-lisp-mode`, and has no bearing on  [Haskell Mode](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_mode_for_Emacs) which is presumably what you want.

If you've correctly set up [inf-haskell.el](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_mode_for_Emacs#inf-haskell.el:_the_best_thing_since_the_breadknife), then `C-c C-i` will bring up a `ghci` session with your current buffer interpreted.

Comment: I have the mode already installed and I want to evaluate a single expression not the buffer.